# how to get access subview of UIView?

Tags: iphone, uiview, subview

according to this code if i want to access imageView1 and imageView2
how can i access to it?
please show me some example

example cell.accessoryView.subviews ?

```
UIImageView *imageView1 = [[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];
UIImageView *imageView2 = [[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];
imageView2.alpha = 0;
[cell.accessoryView addSubview:imageView1];
[cell.accessoryView addSubview:imageView2];
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can use view's tag property:

```
UIImageView *imageView1 = [[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];
imageView1.tag = 100;
UIImageView *imageView2 = [[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];
imageView2.tag = 200;
imageView2.alpha = 0;
[cell.accessoryView addSubview:imageView1];
[cell.accessoryView addSubview:imageView2];
```

And later get subview using `-viewWithTag:` method:

```
UIImageView *getImageView1 = (UIImageView*)[cell.accessoryView viewWithTag:100];
```

Answer (score 10):

I believe u can access all subviews in superview simply by calling
`[cell.accessoryView subviews]`.